# dotnet cli <> VS2017 nuget packages restore errors

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, dotnet-cli

I've used `dotnet cli (2.0.0)` to create 2 projects:

1. `dotnet new webapi` (name: webapiProject)
2. `dotnet new xunit` (name: testProject)

after that, on `testProject` project:
`dotnet add reference webapiProject`

test project is an integration test and it uses webapiProjects `Startup`.
when i do `dotnet run` on xunit one, all works fine. tests run, references work, all good.

But, when i load `testProject.csproj` in `VS2017 (15.3.3)`, i get nuget **NU1105** error:

*Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   NU1105  Unable to find project information for 'webapiProject'. The project file may be invalid or missing targets required for restore.*

I am actually rather new to `dotnet cli` and i am not even sure i should be loading `*.csproj` in VS2017 but i did so because when i opened only my test class then i didn't have intellisense for it.

So, any advice would be highly appreciated about both:

1. the error
2. correct workflow

Comment: You should create a blank solution and then add the two projects. I don't think VS works well if you only open one project.

Comment: @LexLi, your comment should be the answer